# Implementing Block List using Symfony-ACL

Tags: acl, symfony

Here is the scenario:
I have a list of Pages that are to be accessed by anyone with ROLE_READER.
However, some specific books should not be accessible or readable to certain readers (even with ROLE_READER).

The creation of another Role such as ROLE_SPECIAL_READER is not user-friendly and so not an option.

Thus, I believe we need some sort of Black List Control.
My question is: 
- Is this achievable using Symfony-ACL?
- If yes, then, how do we do this?

Thanks and Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple use case, I suggest you use `Voter` instead of `ACL` as the [document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) suggests it might overkill for this kind of use cases.

If you are using voter, you can [write your custom voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html#creating-the-custom-voter) where you will have access to `User` object as well as `Page` object and you can decide which users have permission and who don't.

Internally, ACL is using it's own voter to check permission. It has another layer to store permissions based on Entities (ROLE, USER, OBJECT) in to database and fetch when required.

From my personal experience (doc says it too), `ACL` is little complication to handle.

More benefit using voter :

1. You can create multiple `Voter` as per your project classification / requirements,
2. Later, if you are changing your mind to use `ACL`, you don't have to change codes in controllers.
3. Easy to debug and light weight.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This is not a simple use case, this is an even more complicated since the Admin has to have the choice to choose which page to be excluded from which user or even groups of users. This is the exact use case of ACL, isnt it?

Comment: Yes, ACL does that. When admin choose the page permission with the user, you need to create ACL `view` maskBuilder accordingly.